# Bedeutungen von "fraglich"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler. Indem ich mir die Bedeutungen von "fraglich" in deutschen Wörterbüchern angeschaut habe, habe ich gemerkt, dass nicht alle davon eindeutig sind. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fraglich) gibt an, dass es eher "zweifelhaft" bedeutet, in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fraglich) liest man einfach "unsicher", [Leo](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/fraglich) neigt auch dazu, sie wie "zweifelhaft" auszulegen ("doubtful" auf Englisch). Welche Bedeutung ist tatsächlich am nächsten? Geht es hier bloß um eine Unsicherheit oder um einen Zweifel?

P.S. Die zweite Bedeutung, "betreffend", meine ich hier gar nicht.

Comment: Als Mutersprachler sehe ich keinen Unterschied in der Bedeutung. "unsicher" betont vielleicht eher die objektiven Fakten, "zweifelhaft" eher das subjektive Empfinden, aber die Situation ist dieselbe.

Answer (score 3):

Die Bedeutung von "unsicher" ist allgemeiner und schließt die Bedeutung von "zweifelhaft" mit ein - daher der Unterschied in den Lexika.

Bei *fraglich* schwingt immer ein Zweifel mit - daher ist "zweifelhaft" die genauere Bedeutungsangabe. Die kritische, skeptische oder zweifelnde Dimension ist dieselbe wie bei *etwas in Frage stellen* ("to question something", "to challenge something").

Comment: Klar, vielen Dank!

Answer (score 0):

"Fraglich" bedeutet einfach wörtlich, dass es sich lohnte, zu dem Sachverhalt eine Frage zu stellen. Nach *was* die Frage tatsächlich fragen würde (sprich, ob sie den gesamten Sachverhalt in Frage stellen würde --> "zweifelhaft" oder nur eine minimale Klarstellung bräuchte -->"unsicher", eventuell sogar nur "betreffend", wird nicht ausgedrückt.)

Comment: Was meinst du mit *wörtlich*? Niemand benutzt *fraglich* in dem Sinn *dass es sich lohnte, eine Frage zu stellen* (*ich habe hier viele interessante Vorschläge, alle fraglich* = *Vorschläge, zu denen es sich lohnte, eine Frage zu stellen*?). Man benutzt es als *zweifelhaft, unsicher*.

Comment: @DavidVogt Man benutzt es auch als "darum geht's". Deshalb finde ich es wichtig, einmal über die wörtliche Bedeutung nachzudenken. *Zweifelhaft* ist durchaus auch nichts anderes als "lohnt sich, eine Frage zu stellen".

Comment: @tofro das funktioniert aber nicht immer. _Merkwürdig_  wird heutzutage nur noch im Sinne von eigenartig gebraucht und nicht mehr im wörtlichen Sinne.

Comment: Worte erhalten ihre Bedeutung durch konventionellen Gebrauch. Von der lexikalischen Struktur, also von der Analyse der Einzelbestandteile eines Wortes, auf die tatsächliche Bedeutung, also den Gebrauch in der Sprache zu schließen, ist ein etymologischer Fehlschluss.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Die Bedeutung der Einzelbestandteile einfach zu ignorieren ist aber genauso falsch.

Comment: Fraglich ist das Adjektiv zu Frage. Unsicher oder zweifelhaft ist nur, was nicht vollständig beantwortet ist. Genau so wird fraglich auch gebraucht. +1